# Android screen resolution and pixel ratio

Tags: android, resolution

Hi[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xc09.png)

Can someone maybe explain me how the screen resolution on a android device is working. On this device i can change the screen from normal to small. The resolution is the same, but the device pixel ratio is different. What is happen with the screen. The reason for my question is that we have some designers that ask for the resolution. But it seems to be the same, but yes the content is smaller, so i don't know what the resolution will be?

Thanks :-)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9sDj.png)

Comment: This should answer your question [What is the difference between px, dip, dp, and sp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple XML for the single screen which targets the device sizes. check the official document for **qualifier**.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

OR

Simply use this library It's awesome -

https://github.com/intuit/sdp